# I have created a desktop assistant program but every time i run the program i keep getting this error. kindly help me

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, portaudio

when i try to install pyaudio it is also showing the following error

> Running setup.py clean for pyaudio Failed to build pyaudio Installing
>   collected packages: pyaudio   Running setup.py install for pyaudio ...
>   error
>       Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-okii4l8n\pyaudio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fpl5yt23\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I have also tried to execute this in many different ids but it is not properly working.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 108, in get_pyaudio
>       import pyaudio ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/study material/python
>   programs/practice programs/jarvis2.py", line 66, in 
>       query = takeCommand().lower()   File "E:/study material/python programs/practice programs/jarvis2.py", line 38, in takeCommand
>       with sr.Microphone() as source:   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 79, in **init**
>       self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 110, in get_pyaudio
>       raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation") AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" from the website listed, but PyAudio is kinda broken...

I had the same error, so what you could do is create a condition that activates a text command line. 
I have a similar code to yours on https://github.com/PythonGuy888/ATLAS where I created said condition as the PC I'm developing the code on can't install PyAudio either.

Comment: thanks for the help but can you tell me that how can i fix the pyaudio problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, PyAudio can't be fixed at the moment... I'll try to upload a working PyAudio to github. I'll post the link as soon as it is available. ;]

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 3.6 and then download PyAudio, because it's not supported on Python > 3.6
If it's not working, delete your current Python version, later you will download it.

Answer (score 0):

Or open cmd.exe and try `pip install pipwin` and then `pipwin install pyaudio`